# cocoa bindings to array controller crash

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have a Core Data Entity with a number of attributes, one is 'sku' and one is 'productDesc'. They are both string values.

I have an array controller for the Entity ProductAC

In my xib file I have 2 text fields.

The sku one will bind to Value ProductAC.selection.sku

I have tried to bind the other one to ProductAC.selection.productDesc but it crashes on load,

[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key productDesc.

I can't work out what the difference is between the 2 and why 1 works but the other doesn't?

Comment: Which class is not key value coding-compliant for the key productDesc? Are the two text fields identical? Did you bind to the same array controller? Are the bindings identical (except for the key)? Does the sku binding work?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to tell which class, this is the error message I get. As far as I can tell the two text fields are identical, I dragged them from the library one after the other. They are bound to the same Array Controller, the sku binding works. If I remove the binding from the text field the app runs,

Comment: Is the error message [<ProductAC 0x60800008ca30> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity ProductAC is not key value coding-compliant for the key "productDesc"? If not, how exactly did you configure the array controller and the binding? Did you bind other controls (like a table view) to the array controller?

Comment: The error message is 2018-08-27 06:32:24.179 BPSApp[21502:3365280] [<AppDelegate 0x6100000a2340> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key productDesc.                       I have a table view/cells bound to the Array Controller which displays the data, and the other text field bound to it as well.

Comment: It looks like you did bind the text field to the app delegate (class `AppDelegate`).

Comment: in the bindings the Value is bound to ProductAC in the dropdown and the label says ProductAC.selection.productDesc, how do I bind this to the Array Controller?

Comment: Add `-NSBindingDebugLogLevel 1` to the Arguments Passed On Launch. Maybe you'll get more info about the error.

Comment: looks like the array controller got accidentally bound to the AppDelegate (think I just have clicked and dragged onto it by mistake - mouse occasionally goes a bit mad) - unbinding it fixed it.